# add_class function is adding a space

Tags: moovweb

I am new to Moovweb. I have _mycart.scss file

```
.mw_iphone {
    .Test {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

In the my_cart.ts file

```
$("./body") {
    add_class("mw_iphone")
}
```

Output is: ->

```
<body class=" mw_iphone">
```

a space is getting added

Please help me to fix this issue

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the behavior with certain old mixers, and this is fixed in newly-released mixers.

See the following examples in the Tritium Tester (click on Mixers to see the mixer version)

simple-mobile 1.0.188 (broken): http://tester.tritium.io/6503ac2acc5d98357619385aaff4a1f393fa4a33

simple-mobile 1.0.224 (good):
http://tester.tritium.io/b7c4b64ba9bec0b229c13fb4b29d3d6c2f547df9

If you can, see if changing the mixer version in `Mixer.lock` file fixes your issue.